# Calling functions meant for threads normally

Tags: c++, multithreading, crash, stdcall

I have a function with the prototype

```
DWORD WINAPI blah(LPVOID arg);
```

Which was meant to be used with CreateThread for a threaded app.

I call it with CreateThread with no problem. But then somewhere else in the code, I call it normally, just by blah(NULL). When it gets to this part, it crashes. Is this because the WINAPI part makes it __stdcall and you can't just call __stdcall functions like that?

Comment: Hard to say without the definition of `blah`. It could be a variety of things.

Comment: What is in the function?  Does it dereference the null pointer you pass?

Comment: No, it doesn't use the argument. I was just wondering if the program would crash because it's __stdcall but I'm calling it not from CreateThread.

Comment: You're asking about a step when you should be asking about the problem. Instead of the subproblem "will this crash because of `__stdcall`", you should just ask about the full problem (allowing us to see the function) "why does this crash when called without `CreateThread` like `...`", which may result in "oh, you can't call it with `__stdcall`." Never ask subproblems, only real problems. On a side note, calling it should be fine.

Comment: Are you calling it directly or through something like a callback?

Answer (score 2):

It is not because of `__stdcall`. Start your program in the debugger and check which line of the code gives you a crash.

Answer (score 0):

The only problem would be if `blah()` specifically calls `TerminateThread(`self`)` to end, instead of just returning off the bottom.  The `CreateThread` call sets up the return address such that when blah() returns, it calls `TerminateThread`.

If *blah()* doesn't have any code like that, then an examination of the code is needed to see if it somehow does something thread specific which makes it fail.  Offhand, I can't think of anything else (besides TerminateThread()) which might cause code written to be a thread which would prevent it from being called directly.